# How can I re-arrange an array to start from the middle?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to re-arrange an array to start from any element.

e.g. `arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

If number select 5 then output

```
arr = [5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4]
```

If number select 3 then output

```
arr = [3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2]
```

If number select 7 then output

```
arr = [7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Any advice or guidance on how I can go about doing this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have sorted array as an input ?

Comment: iterate from i to length, select array index `(i + offset) % array-length`

Comment: Simple array rotation with an offset.

Comment: a bit of math and [arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) - if only to output, just a bit of math

Comment: for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1 ; i++){
                    newArray[i] = array[(i+a) % array.length];
                }

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this Javascript code. You can change the var `select` to get the desired output.

```
var select = 5;
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var newArr =[];

if(select <= arr.length && select > 0) {
  for (var i = select-1; i < (select + arr.length -1); i++) {
    newArr.push(arr[i % arr.length]);
  }
}

console.log(newArr)
```

The output is

```
 [5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: As can be seen in the tags, OP are using / want to use Java to achieve this. They never talk about using JS

Comment: for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1 ; i++){
                    newArray[i] = array[(i+a) % array.length];
                }

Comment: @LinosaysReinstateMonica Its the algorithm what matters to the one who asked the question.